# navigationLinksHidden, streetNamesHidden not working on iOS Google Maps SDK 2.0

Tags: ios, google-maps, sdk, maps

I just updated my iOS Xcode project to iOS Google Maps SDK version 2. Before that, for street view panos, I used the navigationLinksHidden and streetNamesHidden attributes set to true and these worked fine. I did not see street names and navigation controls on the pano:

viewPano.navigationLinksHidden = true

viewPano.streetNamesHidden = true

When I updated to Google Maps SDK version 2 however (and fixes several migration issues), street view works again, however, I can not get the attributes above to work. I see the navigation links and street names on the pano view even though I set them to be hidden. Is this a known problem with Google Maps iOS SDK version 2? Is there some other way in version 2 to hide these?

I am using Xcode 8, swift 3 and iOS 10.